# css - container not match inner clipped element

Tags: html, css, clip

I try to put a inner clipped image into a container but looks like it not exactly put at the center of container!

What's the correct way to do match to position the inner element exactly at center of the container?

[image]

```css
.container {
     position: relative;
     width: 130px;     
     height: 130px;
     overflow: hidden;
     border: 5px solid #e0e0ef;
     border-radius:50%;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: -140px;/**/
  left: -160px;/**/
  clip-path: circle(60px at 200px 220px);
  background-color: #ece0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="inner"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Crateva_religiosa.jpg/440px-Crateva_religiosa.jpg" alt="alternatetext">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what your looking for? I updated the `clip-path: circle()` declaration and specifically the two `position` values. The circles radius of 60px was unchanged, but the position values for the center of the circle were changed to appear more centered in the parent container.

```css
.container {
     position: relative;
     width: 130px;     
     height: 130px;
     overflow: hidden;
     border: 5px solid #e0e0ef;
     border-radius:50%;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: -140px;/**/
  left: -160px;/**/
  clip-path: circle(60px at 225px 205px);
  background-color: #ece0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="inner"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Crateva_religiosa.jpg/440px-Crateva_religiosa.jpg" alt="alternatetext">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the top/left with calc function!

```css
.container {
     position: relative;
     width: 130px;     
     height: 130px;
     overflow: hidden;
     border: 5px solid #e0e0ef;
     border-radius:50%;
}
.inner {
  --x: 200px;
  --y: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(60px + 5px - var(--y));
  left: calc(60px + 5px - var(--x));
  clip-path: circle(60px at var(--x) var(--y));
  background-color: #ece0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="inner" style="--x:150px;--y:100px"   src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Crateva_religiosa.jpg/440px-Crateva_religiosa.jpg" alt="alternatetext">
</div>
```